# How to load javascript from parent into child context

Tags: javascript, html

I have one HTML page with parent.js in it. Within that html, one iFrame will be created on runtime. This iframe needs the parent.js in its context.
If I am having one

```
function save() { ... }
```

in the parent.js, I can call that from iframe.js, like

```
parent.save();
```

But i need to call that in the iframe context, like

```
save();
```

So I have loaded the parent.js again in the iframe html. This makes parent.js to be loaded everytime I create a new iframe.

Is there anyway I could reuse the parent.js which is already loaded, into each iframe created?, like

```
loadParentJS("parent.js");
```

within iframe.js. This shouldn't give another request to application server.

Comment: it should not be too much of a hit to load it each time in the iframe, because the user's browser will cache the file.

Comment: yes but if it is cached on the user's browser then it should only download once from the server.

Comment: Yes, it is taking js from cache. server request takes around 600 ms to complete the process, in that nearly 300 ms is taken to GET all the js files. I took this data from firebug

Comment: Okay. Your line "in the parent.js, I can call that from iframe.js, like" seems incorrect.. is it the other way around?

Comment: it's like,--> If I am having one `function save() { ... }` in the parent.js,  I can call that from iframe.js, like `parent.save();`. <Its a single statement>

Comment: Okay. How do you pass in 'parent' to the iframe context? Can I see that code, too?

Comment: `parent` object will be available in iframe context by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate your code in parent.js in a closure:

```
var loadParentJS = function(window) {
    window.save = function() {
      // code
    };

    window.other = function() {
      // code
    };

  // rest of your code...

};

loadParentJS(window);
```

Then in your iframe, run this:

```
parent.loadParentJS(window);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. In my case, i don't want to change code in iframe. So adding `parent.loadParentJS(window);` in iframe js is giving the parent context into the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

In your parent.js file, preceed each function and variable with `this.` and then you should be able to take advantage of Javascript Closures.

Replace: `function save() { ... }` 
With: `this.save = function() { ... }`

Replace: `var aVariable = "value";`
With: `this.aVariable = "value";`

Then in your iframe you need to set the scope of `this` to `parent`:

`this = parent`;

All of your calls to functions or variables in parent.js (in the global javascript or in the iframe javascript) will look like this:

```
this.save();
alert(this.aVariable);
```

Comment: If that does not work then I can point you to a Javascript Module Design reference.. it may require some rework to encapsulate your parent.js code in a self-executing anonymous function.

Comment: in iframe script i do not want to change anything except some static code. Its because, a lot of custom written script will be executed in iframe level. That encapsulation you have mentioned here, i think @jalbee given the same. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: `this.` will give the current context. but iframe js code is written by so many people and changing that all is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no you can't. the content of IFrame is handled as a separate web page. 
Longer answer: are you sure you need to use IFrame? what is it for? can you avoid it?
using IFrame is not a bad thing, just maybe it doesn't fullfill your needs

You should read a bit about cross domain communication. This will give you an idea on how to communicate between your web page and the IFrame inside it

[cross domain communication](http://css.dzone.com/articles/cross-domain-communication)

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But im not trying to connect cross domain pages here and the communication between parent and iframe is working fine already

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can pass the `document` or `window` to the save function to manipulate the context.

---

For example, accept the document as a parameter:

```
function save(doc) { doc.getObjectById("myform").submit(); }
```

Then:

```
parent.save(document);
```

---

Or accept the window as the parameter:

```
function save(win) { alert(win.myvariable) }
```

And then:

```
parent.save(self);
```

Comment: I cannot opt to change the parameters of the functions as they were standard functions for the application. Thanks for the reply